# using a counter for all groups members in for-each-group

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a problem where I have an xml content with different keys needs to be grouped together and displayed, when displayed there is a pagination so I can't display all entries on the same page, I'm using for-each-group for grouping the items, and loop through each current-group() and display its item, the xml is something like this:

```
<entry>
    <key>key1</key>
    <value>value1</value>
</entry>

<entry>
    <key>key2</key>
    <value>value2</value>
</entry>

<entry>
    <key>key1</key>
    <value>value3</value>
</entry>
<entry>
    <key>key1</key>
    <value>value4</value>
</entry>
<entry>
    <key>key3</key>
    <value>value5</value>
</entry>
<entry>
    <key>key2</key>
    <value>value6</value>
</entry>
<entry>
    <key>key4</key>
    <value>value7</value>
</entry>
<entry>
    <key>key3</key>
    <value>value8</value>
</entry>
<entry>
    <key>key5</key>
    <value>value9</value>
</entry>
<entry>
    <key>key1</key>
    <value>value10</value>
</entry>
<entry>
    <key>key2</key>
    <value>value11</value>
</entry>
```

which should display like:

Page1:

```
key1
    value1
    value3
    value4
    value10

key2 
    value2
    value6
    value11
key3
    value5
    value8
key4
    value7
```

Page2:

```
 key5
    value9
```

the xsl I'm using without pagination is

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="entry" group-by="key">
    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="current-grouping()">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

I need to display only 10 items on each page, how can I get the count of preceding entries of current-grouping()

edit for more info:

I have a variable $size and $offsite, what I'm basically trying to do is something like :

```
<xsl:if test="$count &gt; $offset and $count &lt;= $offset + $size">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
</xsl:if>
```

where $count would have the count of all items already rendered, ideally if some how I can create a counter similar to position() in for-each but it doesn't restart with each loop of current-group().

if I don't want group items by key, I would have done something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="entry">
        <xsl:if test="position() &gt; $offset and position() &lt;= $offset + $size">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

but now since I'm using for-each-group, and the entries of each group are looped through individually, how can I keep track of entries that are already rendered from preceding groups.

Comment: Please show us an example of more than 10 entries and the expected resulting code of transforming that example.

Comment: I updated the example to have more than 10 entries

Comment: Actually, show a _complete_ input XML document, and a _complete_ stylesheet: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: The complete styelsheet is more than 1000 lines, and the xml is much more than that, I just added the related part, is there anything related I can add here that can help? why is the info I added is not enough ?

Comment: What is your output format, HTML, some other XML format (XSL-FO?), plain text?

Comment: Html, each entry is a div and the key is a header, its something similar to a search results page

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I added more details in the original question

Comment: There is no "pagination" as such in XSLT or in HTML, so this part of your question is not clear.

Comment: I don't see your code create any `div` or other HTML elements. And it is not clear what you consider a page? Are you trying to print that HTML generated by your XSLT and want to use CSS with properties like `page-break-before`? Or do you want to create several documents and an index document that allows accessing the different "pages"?

Comment: $offset is passed to xsl depending on a request parameter, depending on the value of the parameter the entries will render, if its 0 then first 10 will render, if its 1 then the next 10, I didn't include the html initially since I was trying keep it minimal, the div is added inside <xsl:template match="entry" /> for each element, and I didn't include the header since I didn't think it would make any difference to the question

Comment: I edited the question again and added more details, please let me know if its still not clear.

Comment: If you are applying the XSLT on the server with each request and you only want to return a certain part of the grouped elements then I would first store the grouped items in a variable and then extract the 10 items you want to return for a "page" requested as needed. A variable in XSLT 2.0 can easily store XML or HTML so it should not be that difficult to adapt your code returning 10 elements from a `for-each` to return 10 elements stored in a variable of grouped elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in two stages - first re-order the whole unpaginated list of entries so they are grouped together by key (i.e. in the order that the final output requires), then take the appropriate page "slice" of that sequence to do the actual transformation:

```
<xsl:variable name="orderedEntries" as="element()*">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="entry" group-by="key">
    <xsl:sequence select="current-group()" />
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each-group select="$orderedEntries[
            position() &gt; $offset and position() &lt;= $offset + $size]"
     group-by="key">
  <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

This will work even if the page break is part way through a group, e.g. an `$offset` and `$size` of 5 given your example input would produce

```
key2 
    value6
    value11
key3
    value5
    value8
key4
    value7
```

---

P.S. as Martin points out in a comment, the

```
  <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>
```

is for most purposes equivalent to simply

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
```

(the only difference being in the values of `position()` and `last()` that the called templates will see)

Comment: The `<xsl:for-each select="current-grouping()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
  </xsl:for-each>` should be `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>`, no?

Comment: @MartinHonnen it could be, yes, I just copied the OP's code (I'm just changing what their `for-each-group` selects, not what it does with the nodes it has selected).  Though I have corrected `current-grouping()` to `current-group()`, thanks for pointing that bit out.

Comment: It might be clearer to use `subsequence($orderedEntries,$offset+1,$size)` as the `select` of the `xsl:for-each-group`.